# C++ Defining Global Variable

Tags: c++

Very simple question:
I was fiddling with  basic C++ (being very new to programming) and I got into trouble while declaring a global variable to do some addition

```
 #include <iostream>
int x,y;
int sum(int, int)
{
    return x + y;
}
int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    cout << "The sum of 10 and 4 is: " << sum(10,4) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Changing "int x,y;" to "int x,y = 0" has the same result: The sum equates to 0.
Could someone explain this odd behavior? Thanks!

Comment: You never modified the value of `x` and `y`.

Comment: @Doorknob why wouldn't it?...

Comment: Hi Jason! welcome to SO. this is not an odd behavior, you don't modify the values of `x` and `y` even you pass it on a function.

Comment: int x, y = 0; this means you declared variable: x, y and according to C++ declaration, you can declare variable of an arbitrary number at once, so they could be 5 or 10 variable. And "= 0" is the assignment. So you have assigned the variables x, y a value of 0. According C++ assignment, you can assign a value to an arbitrary number of variables with only one assignment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function always returns the sum of global variables `x` and `y`, which are always `0`. `x` and `y` are implicitly set to zero at the program startup. You never change their values, so they remain zero forever. The sum of two zeros is zero, no surprise here.

You pass `10` and `4` to your function, but the function itself completely ignores what is passed to it, i.e. it ignores its parameters (they are not even named). It always sums global `x` and `y`, which are always `0`.

If you want your function to sum its arguments, you have to name the function parameters and use them

```
int sum(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}
```

And now you don't need any global variables at all. (`main` remains as is.)

Alternatively, if you so desire, you can get rid of the parameters completely and sum the global variables instead

```
int x,y;
int sum()
{
    return x + y;
}
```

but in this case you will have to pass the values to sum through those global variables, not as function arguments

```
int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    x = 10;
    y = 4;
    cout << "The sum of 10 and 4 is: " << sum() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This latter approach is here just for illustrative purposes. It is definitely not a good programming practice.

What you have in your code is a weird disconnected hybrid of these two approaches, which can't possibly work.

Comment: Ahh alright. A C++ website said that "global variables are dangerous because their values can be changed by any function that is called". I guess it just doesn't work the way I did it.

Comment: @Jason Guo: They *can* be changed. But you never change them in your original code.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why the latter is an unhealthy practice? I understand that using global variables is not good, but could you give examples to show the implications of such usage? Or is there something else in the last approach that is unhealthy?

Comment: @JasonGuo: The problem isn't in small programs, but if you have something the size of say FireFox, there are literally millions of lines of code which can change `x`. So if `x` gets an unexpected value, you might be forced to check all of them. In comparison, a variable defined inside a function is much easier to check.

Answer (score 1):

In order to fix the issue, the thing requires changing is the sum function.

```
int sum(int a, int b){

    return a+b;  //a,b here are referring to the inputs, while what you did was referring to the global variable..
}
```

Besides, try not to use global variables, usually you would end up with lots of troubles.

Another thing, I don't think your way of defining a function is correct. The inputs have to look like this instead:

```
int sum(int a, int b)
```

Unless you wanna declare the function first and provide the actual implementation later, you are not suppose to miss the name of the inputs!

Answer (score 1):

when you are just globally declare the variables x,y ,they implicitly set to zero value.in your function definition,you are just giving  the datantype of args, not the args names.so when you returning the sum of x,y ,it returns zero.and the value passed by the main function goes nowhere.
your program must look like this

```
#include<iostream>
int x,y;
int sum(x,y)
{
return x+y;
}
int main()
{
int v,a,b;
cout<<"values of a and b";
cin>>a>>b;

v=sum(a,b)
cout<<"their sum is"<<v;
}
    when you explicitly define the value in second case
```

i.e `int x,y=0;`
you are just explicitly giving the value of value y to 0 while the x implicitly remains 0 and since you are not giving the args name,the ultimately result return biy the function is zero,

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you only need x and y inside your add function, so make them local to the function. There is no reason to make them global. Follow the "least accessibility" idiom to prevent other parts of your program from mistakenedly modifying variables.

You might need a global variable supposed you want to define a well known parameter that every function needs to know and yet modifiable during run time. If you want it fixed, then a global constant would be more proper.

Hope that helps.